# Concatenate distinct values from multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have this in a table

```
party1 | party2
A      | E 
B      | D
C      | H
D      | B
E      | A
F      | H 
G      | I
```

Result I am trying to get is distinct concatenation of `party1` and `party2`, i.e.

```
AE (will same as EA so only one instance is required)
BD (will same as DB so only one instance is required)
CH
FH
GI
```

Party1 and Party2 are formed using CTE. Parties A-I flows from single table Party and are identified as party1 and party2  using business logic of code 4 and 1.

Below is the query i could form

```
WITH CTE AS
(
      SELECT 
    DISTINCT CPR1.PARTY_IDENTIFIER AS PARTY1,
             CPR2.PARTY_IDENTIFIER AS PARTY2,
             CCR.CLIENT_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_CODE,
             CPR1.CLIENT_TYPE_CODE
        FROM GOLD.CLIENT_TO_PARTY_RELATIONSHIP CPR1
        JOIN GOLD.CLIENT_TO_CLIENT_RELATIONSHIP CCR 
          ON     CPR1.CLIENT_IDENTIFIER = CCR.CLIENT_IDENTIFIER 
             AND CCR.CLIENT_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_CODE = '04'
             AND CPR1.CLIENT_TYPE_CODE = '1'
        JOIN GOLD.CLIENT_TO_PARTY_RELATIONSHIP CPR2 
          ON CPR2.CLIENT_IDENTIFIER = CCR.CLIENT_IDENTIFIER
       WHERE (CPR1.PARTY_IDENTIFIER_INACTIVE_DATE IS NULL OR CPR1.PARTY_IDENTIFIER_INACTIVE_DATE ='')
         AND (CPR2.PARTY_IDENTIFIER_INACTIVE_DATE IS NULL OR CPR2.PARTY_IDENTIFIER_INACTIVE_DATE ='')
         AND CPR1.PARTY_IDENTIFIER<>CPR2.PARTY_IDENTIFIER
         AND CPR1.DATA_AS_OF_DATE LIKE '201912%' 
         AND CPR2.DATA_AS_OF_DATE LIKE '201912%'
         AND CCR.DATA_AS_OF_DATE LIKE '201912%'
)

  SELECT 
DISTINCT CONCAT("PG","_",TRIM(CAST(PARTY1 AS STRING)) ,"_",TRIM(CAST(PARTY1 AS STRING))) AS PG_KEY,
         party1,
         party2
    FROM CTE
```

Comment: Please post more information. Schemas, data, queries

Comment: Both Party1 and Party2 have extra column as ID, so party1.ID = party2.ID

Answer (score 0):

Your description says that you are actually not interested in the concatenation but in the (2-element) sets that are composed from the paired data. Representing them (as you do) as a 2-letter string, go along the following template.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
      SELECT CPR1.PARTY_IDENTIFIER AS PARTY1,
             CPR2.PARTY_IDENTIFIER AS PARTY2,
             CCR.CLIENT_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_CODE,
             CPR1.CLIENT_TYPE_CODE
        FROM GOLD.CLIENT_TO_PARTY_RELATIONSHIP CPR1
        JOIN GOLD.CLIENT_TO_CLIENT_RELATIONSHIP CCR 
          ON     CPR1.CLIENT_IDENTIFIER = CCR.CLIENT_IDENTIFIER 
             AND CCR.CLIENT_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_CODE = '04'
             AND CPR1.CLIENT_TYPE_CODE = '1'
        JOIN GOLD.CLIENT_TO_PARTY_RELATIONSHIP CPR2 
          ON CPR2.CLIENT_IDENTIFIER = CCR.CLIENT_IDENTIFIER
       WHERE (CPR1.PARTY_IDENTIFIER_INACTIVE_DATE IS NULL OR CPR1.PARTY_IDENTIFIER_INACTIVE_DATE ='')
         AND (CPR2.PARTY_IDENTIFIER_INACTIVE_DATE IS NULL OR CPR2.PARTY_IDENTIFIER_INACTIVE_DATE ='')
         AND CPR1.PARTY_IDENTIFIER<>CPR2.PARTY_IDENTIFIER
         AND CPR1.DATA_AS_OF_DATE LIKE '201912%' 
         AND CPR2.DATA_AS_OF_DATE LIKE '201912%'
         AND CCR.DATA_AS_OF_DATE LIKE '201912%'
)
  select
distinct CASE WHEN party1 < party2 
              THEN party1 || party2 
              ELSE party2 || party1
         END pair
         FROM CTE
       ;
```

***Caveats***

Pull the CTE definition out of the subquery. Concat syntax may vary depending on the sql dialect / database product you are using.